# Cron job in custom module not appearing in Cron Settings (using Elysia Cron)

Tags: cron

Very strange problem that I cannot find anyone else having. I have a custom module and am using hook_cron(), but the cron job is not appearing in /admin/config/system/cron of my Drupal 7 site.  All the other cron jobs I created through custom modules are there, and I did not think I did anything different.

Here is my function, in a file called file_handler.module

```
function file_handler_cron() {
   $log_file = '/www/anon_site.org/htdocs/sites/all/modules/custom/file_handler/log.txt';
   $log_file_size = exec("du -h $log_file", $output, $return_size);
   $size = substr($log_file_size, 0, strpos($log_file_size, '  '));   
   $measure = substr($size, -1);   //K, M, G, etc.
   $num = str_replace($measure, '', $size);  //4.0

   if ($measure == 'G' || $measure == 'T') {
       file_unmanaged_delete($path);
   }
   elseif ($measure == 'M' && $num > 10) {
       file_unmanaged_delete($path);
   }
   else {
       //log is small and does not need to be deleted
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think D7 lists cron jobs on that page. Are you using a module to list the custom crons perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for laying out the code in a readable format!  Sorry this is my first ever stack exchange question.  We are using Elysia cron.  I have also tried using a hook_cronapi with the set parameters and again, no dice.  My team members are really perplexed so I wondered if anyone else had an idea what the problem is.

Comment: You should add Elysia Cron to the question, otherwise people may assume it's the bog standard poormanscron that comes with Drupal out of the box.

Comment: Just an update that I tested this on the stage server and everything worked perfectly!  So the dev server must have messed up configurations. Nothing wrong with the code for once.